# Core Dumped when reading in a string?

Tags: c++, string

I'm working on a intro-C++ assignment where I have to read in a string, then count the frequency of letters within the string itself, and output the results. I'm not allowed to modify any of my function headers (if I could I probably wouldn't be here right now), and I see to have most of the more difficult parts down. The only issue I'm getting is that I was previously able to read in my string, but my program wasn't able to count the occurance of the first character correctly. After I fixing that, I ended up with a segmentation fault in my function for reading in my string. My Code so far is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//FUNCTION PROTOTYPES 

string getPhrase(const string & prompt);   
int charIndex(const vector<char> & list, char letter);
void addLetter(vector<char> & letters, vector<int> & freqs, char letter);

int main()
{
    // Define your local variables
const int COLUMNWIDTH = 2;  //will be used in later functions
vector<char> letters;  //list of letters in the string
vector<int> freqs;     //corresponding list of frequencies of letters
vector<char> list;     //not so sure whats up with this, but it
char letter;           //the current letter 
int index =-1;         //index location of letter, if == -1, then letter is not currently indexed and needs to be
string prompt;  //user input statement 

//Input string
const string phrase = getPhrase(prompt); 


    int i =0;
while (phrase[i] == ' ')//determine first term of phrase that isn't a space, then make that space the first term of list so next loop can run
  {
    i++;
  }
list[0] = phrase[i];

for (int i = 0; i<phrase.length(); i++)
  {
    index = charIndex(list,phrase[i]);
    if (phrase[i]!= ' ')
      {
    if (index == -1) 
      {
        letter = phrase[i];
        addLetter(letters, freqs, letter);
        list = letters;
        index = charIndex(list,letter);
      }
      }
  }


  return 0;
}



// FUNCTION DEFINITIONS GO HERE:
string getPhrase(const string &prompt)
{
  string phrase;
  std::cout<<"Enter phrase: ";    //**ERROR IS OCCURING HERE **
  std::getline(cin, phrase);      //**ERROR IS OCCURING HERE **

  return phrase;
}



 //determine the index location of the specific letter 
 int charIndex(const vector<char> &list, char letter)

 {
   int i = 0;
   int index = -1;
   while ( i <= list.size())
     {
       if (letter == list[i])
     {
       index = i;
       if (index != -1)
         {
           i = list.size() +1;
         }
     }
       i++;
     }
   return (index);
 }    

//addLetter adds the new letter to the list of letters, and the corresponding frequency list is changed 
void addLetter(vector<char> & letters, vector<int> & freqs, char letter)  
{
  letters.push_back(letter);
  freqs.push_back(1);

}
```

There are a lot of "const" I wish I was able to remove, but I can't. I also have gone through and determined that the error is occuring in my "getPhrase" function at my "getLine", and have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: Things are usually `const` for a very good reason, and it's in your best interest to learn to mark everything that should be `const` appropriately.

Comment: What is the purpose of `string prompt`, and its use as a parameter in `string getPhrase(const string& prompt)`? You don't seem to be doing anything with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The segfault occurs at:

```
list[0] = phrase[i];
```

Because although you declared `list` as a vector, you haven't actually allocated any elements yet, so `[0]` doesn't exist. One way to fix it is by doing this:

```
list.push_back(phrase[i]);
```